# How to generate discrete data to pass into a contour plot using pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have two sets of continuous data that I would like to pass into a contour plot. The x-axis would be time, the y-axis would be mass, and the z-axis would be frequency (as in how many times that data point appears). However, most data points are not identical but rather very similar. Thus, I suspect it's easiest to discretize both the x-axis and y-axis.

Here's the data I currently have:

**INPUT**

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df['Dates'].head(5)
df['Mass'].head(5)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
13   2003-05-09
14   2003-09-09
15   2010-01-18
16   2010-11-21
17   2012-06-29
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

13    2500.0
14    3500.0
15    4000.0
16    4500.0
17    5000.0
Name: Mass, dtype: float64
```

I'd like to convert the data such that it groups up data points within the year (ex: all datapoints taken in 2003) and it groups up data points within different levels of mass (ex: all datapoints between 3000-4000 kg). Next, the code would count how many data points are within each of these blocks and pass that as the z-axis.

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to adjust the levels of slices. Ex: grouping points up every 100kg instead of 1000kg, or passing a custom list of levels that aren't equally distributed. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: have a look at `np.histogram2d`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is pd.cut

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

n = 10
scale = 1e3
Min = 0
Max = 1e4

np.random.seed(6)

Start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
Dates = np.array([base + datetime.timedelta(days=i*180) for i in range(n)])
Mass = np.random.rand(n)*10000
df = pd.DataFrame(index = Dates, data = {'Mass':Mass})

print(df)
```

gives you:

```
                   Mass
2000-01-01  8928.601514
2000-06-29  3319.798053
2000-12-26  8212.291231
2001-06-24   416.966257
2001-12-21  1076.566799
2002-06-19  5950.520642
2002-12-16  5298.173622
2003-06-14  4188.074286
2003-12-11  3354.078493
2004-06-08  6225.194322
```

if you want to group your Masses by say 1000, or implement your own custom bins, you can do this:

```
Bins,Labels=np.arange(Min,Max+.1,scale),(np.arange(Min,Max,scale))+(scale)/2
EqualBins = pd.cut(df['Mass'],bins=Bins,labels=Labels)
df.insert(1,'Equal Bins',EqualBins)

Bins,Labels=[0,1000,5000,10000],['Small','Medium','Big']
CustomBins = pd.cut(df['Mass'],bins=Bins,labels=Labels)
df.insert(2,'Custom Bins',CustomBins)
```

If you want to just show the year, month, etc it is very simple:

```
df['Year'] = df.index.year
df['Month'] = df.index.month
```

but you can also do custom date ranges if you like:

```
Bins=[datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31),datetime.datetime(2000, 9, 1),
      datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1),datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 1)]


Labels = ['Early','Middle','Late']
CustomDateBins = pd.cut(df.index,bins=Bins,labels=Labels)
df.insert(3,'Custom Date Bins',CustomDateBins)

print(df)
```

This yields something like what you want:

```
                   Mass Equal Bins Custom Bins Custom Date Bins  Year  Month
2000-01-01  8928.601514     8500.0         Big            Early  2000      1
2000-06-29  3319.798053     3500.0      Medium            Early  2000      6
2000-12-26  8212.291231     8500.0         Big           Middle  2000     12
2001-06-24   416.966257      500.0       Small           Middle  2001      6
2001-12-21  1076.566799     1500.0      Medium           Middle  2001     12
2002-06-19  5950.520642     5500.0         Big             Late  2002      6
2002-12-16  5298.173622     5500.0         Big             Late  2002     12
2003-06-14  4188.074286     4500.0      Medium             Late  2003      6
2003-12-11  3354.078493     3500.0      Medium             Late  2003     12
2004-06-08  6225.194322     6500.0         Big             Late  2004      6
```

The .groupby function is probably of interst to you as well:

```
yeargroup = df.groupby(df.index.year).mean()
massgroup = df.groupby(df['Equal Bins']).count()
print(yeargroup)
print(massgroup)

             Mass    Year     Month
2000  6820.230266  2000.0  6.333333
2001   746.766528  2001.0  9.000000
2002  5624.347132  2002.0  9.000000
2003  3771.076389  2003.0  9.000000
2004  6225.194322  2004.0  6.000000
            Mass  Custom Bins  Custom Date Bins  Year  Month
Equal Bins                                                  
500.0          1            1                 1     1      1
1500.0         1            1                 1     1      1
2500.0         0            0                 0     0      0
3500.0         2            2                 2     2      2
4500.0         1            1                 1     1      1
5500.0         2            2                 2     2      2
6500.0         1            1                 1     1      1
7500.0         0            0                 0     0      0
8500.0         2            2                 2     2      2
9500.0         0            0                 0     0      0
```